# Is is possible to set m2m object not to have recursive relation to itself?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have a User model that has a m2m `subscribers` relation with itself.

The idea is that user can't be subscribed on himself.

Is it possible to handle this at models level?

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe a User to itself?

Comment: @Gocht Yes, it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a strong constraint on your design, I would let the database know about it and enforce it on the database itself. The corresponding SQL would look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "myapp_subscribers" ADD CONSTRAINT "myapp_subscribers_not_self" CHECK (user1_id <> user2_id)
```

*Replace `user1_id` and `user2_id` with the actual field names, `myapp_` with the actual name of your app and `not_self` with whatever name you want to give the constraint, it does not matter as long as its purpose is obvious to you.*

While Django does not provide automation for this kind of things, it's pretty easy to write a custom migration step yourself. If you are creating a new app, in the migration file generated by Django, add this at the end of the list of migration steps:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
    [('ALTER TABLE "myapp_subscribers" ADD CONSTRAINT "myapp_subscribers_not_self" CHECK (user1_id <> user2_id);', None)],
    [('ALTER TABLE "myapp_subscribers" DROP CONSTRAINT "myapp_subscribers_not_self";', None)]
)
```

The second SQL line allows the operation to be reversed. If you omit it, Django will refuse to run the migration backwards.

If you are changing an existing app, include that in the migration you're creating, or create an empty migration.

```
./manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp
```

Once you add the constraint, the database will enforce it, and prevent any attempt, be it from django or anything else, to subscribe a user to himself.

On the Django side, that means that any attempt to do so will raise an [`IntegrityError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError). If inside a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly), this will also cause the transaction to rollback cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `m2m_changed` signal with a "`pre_add`" action to validate the adding object. [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)